# No longer receiving inv messages from node

Tags: network

I've written my own simple client that connects to my local node. It has been working fine, but after upgrading from **13.1** to **14.1** my local node is no longer sending my client `inv` messages.

The handshake seems to be working fine, as follows:

```
Client: version
Node:   version
Node:   verack
......
```

But after the `verack`, the node does not send any more data to me. I usually get a `ping` after the `verack`, but that's not coming through either.

Any ideas why this might be happening? Here's the payload of the verack I'm receiving, if it's any use:

```
37663131303130303064303030303030303030303030303035613034313735393030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303064303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303034626363303539623666653837346333323132663533363137343666373336383639336133303265333133343265333132383463363536313732366534643635343134323639373436333666363936653239326631363164303730303031
```

Comment: +2 Thanks for sharing your discovery with us!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of **0.14.0**, when you receive a `verack`, you also need to send a `verack` message back.

So whereas before you could do this:

```
Client: version
Node:   version
Node:   verack
......
```

You now need to do this:

```
Client: version
Node:   version
Node:   verack
Client: verack  <- do this!
......
```

---

**Links**

- https://bitcoin.org/en/release/v0.14.0 (#9715)
- https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/9715